# Displaying ALL products on the home page (New, Featured, Sale basically everything)

Tags: blocks, products, slider

I'm trying to add a product slider at my website's home page. I have tried using almost all the `{{block type="catalog/xxxxx"}}` but I cannot get it to display **ALL PRODUCTS** in the home page's content.
I know it's possible to get New products or Featured Products, but having all of them in a single slider doesn't seem to work. I have spent hours now trying to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Note: I have previously been able to achieve this but the code doesn't work anymore!** 
I'm using Ultimo theme by Rainforest, if it helps!

**EDIT:**
I've also tried using the below

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

but this causes the HTML code to break and results in the content below the homepage (i.e footer, link etc to disappear).

Comment: post your code.

Comment: `{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}` 

Even this doesn't work, I believe it should but it only breaks my page and the footer disappears. The only thing I see on the page is the Header and the slideshow

Comment: Turn on error displaying and check magento adn apache logs for errors

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you need to create your own module and inside it create this block

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Product_All extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'visibility', 'in'=>"2,3,4")));
            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

Then create the template `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/[namespace]_[module]/product/all.phtml` where you place your markup.
Something like this (will require styling):

```
    <?php 
    $products = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
        <div>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

now you can use it in your homepage like this

```
{{block type="[block_alias]/product_all" template="[namespace]_[module]/product/all.phtml"}}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort in answering my question. However, like my question suggests, I have been able to do this before using just the {{block....}}. But, it wouldn't work anymore? Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: @NavikGoswami. I don't...If I did, I wouldn't have written a full book as an answer.